# processing controller actions as JS instead of HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have the following form:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'profile', :action => 'follow_topic'), :remote => true do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :topic_id, topic_id %>
  <%= content_tag :button, :class => 'link', :onclick => "javascript:document.getElementById('followtopic#{Topic.find(topic_id).identifier}').innerHTML='Following...'" do %> Follow <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and I'm trying to get the controller to process it as JS in place of HTML. The funny thing is I have a form exactly like this in another spot in the app that seems to work fine, and the controller definitions are the same. Can't quite figure out the problem. Any ideas on what I should be checking first?

```
def follow_topic
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  current_user.follows << @topic
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: For anyone coming here as of ~2020 - strongly consider sending HTML over the wire and using something like Stimulus JS to handle where / when / how that html should be integrated into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You got it right except your format.js isn't doing anything. What are you expecting in your form submit? and what are you expecting in return? a json or http response 200?

specify that in your format.js like so:

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :nothing => true, :response => :ok if current_user.follows << @topic  } 
end
...
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: I've added render :nothing => true, :response => :ok and it still gets processed as HTML and redirects the page to /profile/follow_topic.

Comment: If you leave `format.js` empty it *should* render a javascript template. In this case `follow_topic.js.erb`.

Comment: hmm so it is the posting that has a problem. in your logs what does it say? something like: 0.0.1 at Mon Aug 08 12:13:29 +0800 2011
  Processing by YourController#action as HTML? or as JS?

Comment: It says processing by controller#action as HTML

Answer (score 0):

This question is OLD but it's unanswered and I just struggled with the same problem for hours, so hopefully this will help someone in future.

Make sure `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And that erb contains `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>` and not just a `<script>` tag.

This is what fixed it for me.