# Rails 4, Ajax, jQuery. Form_for with remote: true is not send as js as it should be

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I recently spent 2 days digging Google and SO. Nothing...

What I am trying to do is very simple.

I have 2 models: Product and Supplier. On the product create form I have fields to assign it to existing suppliers. And also have the link 'Create new supplier' if the supplier is not on the list.

This link when clicked shows the form for the new supplier (it is making request to Suppliers#new and renders the new supplier form), but when hit submit, the form is send normally as http post request to SuppliersController#create. It should be sent through Ajax so I could get response as js (from respond_to ... format.js in Supplier create method) back to Products create form. Instead it redirects to show supplier page in supplier controller.

Here is similar problem on SO:

[processing controller actions as JS instead of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977603/processing-controller-actions-as-js-instead-of-html)

And I know it should be JS. I also have js.erb files done accordingly to action names.

This is my Product controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /products
      # GET /products.json
      def index
        @products = Product.includes(:product_suppliers).order('name').order('product_suppliers.price_product_supplier DESC')


      end

      # GET /products/1
      # GET /products/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /products/new
      def new
        @product = Product.new
        @product.product_suppliers.new

      end

      # GET /products/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /products
      # POST /products.json
      def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)
    #    @product.product_suppliers.find_by_product_id(@product.id).update_attributes(price_product_supplier: params[:price])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
            format.js
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.js
          end
        end

      end

      # PATCH/PUT /products/1
      # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.update(product_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
            format.js
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.js
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /products/1
      # DELETE /products/1.json
      def destroy
        @product.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.js
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_product
          @product = Product.find(params[:id])
          if @product.product_suppliers.exists?
            return true
          else
            @product.product_suppliers.new
          end
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def product_params
          params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, product_suppliers_attributes: [:id, :supplier_id, :project_id, :price_product_supplier, :_destroy])
        end
    end
```

And its form partial (product_supplier is a join model with hmt relation between products and suppliers:

```
= form_for @product do |f|
      - if @product.errors.any?
        #error_explanation
          %h2
            = pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error")
            prohibited this product from being saved:
          %ul
            - @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
              %li= message

      .field
        = f.label :name
        %br/
        = f.text_field :name

      .field
        = f.label :description
        %br/
        = f.text_area :description

      .product-suppliers
        = f.nested_fields_for :product_suppliers, wrapper_tag: :div, wrapper_options: { class: "row" } do |ps|
          = ps.label :name
          = ps.collection_select :supplier_id, Supplier.all, :id, :name, prompt: true
          = ps.label :price_product_supplier
          = ps.text_field :price_product_supplier
          = ps.remove_nested_fields_link
        = f.add_nested_fields_link :product_suppliers, "Match another supplier"
        or 
        = link_to "Create new supplier", new_supplier_path, id: "supplier_new", remote: true         

      .field
        .actions
          = f.submit 'Save'
```

Supplier controller looks as after scaffolding, but instead format.json, there is format.js with no attrs. Form for supplier:

```
<%= form_for @supplier, remote: true, authenticity_token: true  do |f| %>
  <% if @supplier.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@supplier.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this supplier from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @supplier.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :telno %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :telno %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance for any response!

Answer (score 0):

I am honestly not entirely sure if I understand your question, but respond_to format.js might not be doing what you think. [Check out this answer to a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545148/rails-respond-to-format-js-api)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick response!

I have edited my question to clarify it a bit more. Sorry for the inconvinience.